# Best way to pass variables around a WordPress site?

Tags: variables, globals

I'm building a membership site with a membership plugin right now. The different types of memberships are associated with IDs and I have to constantly do things like "show this if the ID is 4122 (i.e. user is a member of group X), but hide otherwise".

For this, I'm constantly looking up the IDs of the various levels and it just dawned on me that this is terribly inefficient.

To get around this, I tried declaring variables at the top of my `functions.php`, i.e. `$gold_member = 4122;`.

I'm a bit of a beginner in php and tried then passing those variables into my functions via `global $gold_member;`. But that didn't work and I also read somewhere that it is considered bad form to use globals.

Is there any standard way of solving this problem? Basically what I'm after is something very similar to how variables are used in SASS or LESS. I want to define them once and then use them in `functions.php` and in the templates.

Comment: Can't you use WordPress roles for this, i.e. make a gold_member role to assign users to?

Comment: There is an excellent answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10963049/2073994

Comment: Use user roles and capabilitis to control what a user can do, including access to content. I think your question is wrong, like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do this using the function [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/wp_get_current_user). This function will get the contents of the [`WP_User`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User) class. It can be stored in a global variable:

```
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
```

`$current_user` will then become [an array](http://wpsmith.net/2012/an-introduction-to-wp_user-class/) matching the properties of `WP_User` for the currently logged in user. If no user is logged in then it will simply return an array with the `ID` having a value of `0`.

You could then do something like:

```
if ( 0 == $current_user->ID ) {
  // Code for No User Logged In
} elseif ( 4122 = $current_user->ID ) {
  // Code for $gold_member
} else {
  // Code for everyone else
}
```

That being said, as Rup noted in his comment, WP User Roles is a more efficient way to determine this over ID. However, since `$current_user` is multi-dimensional array, you will need to either [write a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990855/php-check-if-value-and-key-exist-in-multidimensional-array) that returns `true` or `false` testing to see if the value exists in it or pull it out and create a second variable and test it:

```
$current_user_roles = $current_user->roles;
if ( in_array( "gold_member", $current_user_roles ) ) {
  // Gold Member Code Here
} else {
  // Code for everyone else here
}
```

I would recommend writing the function since you can potentially re-use it elsewhere and it doesn't involve another variable/global.